# org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [userId]

Tags: hibernate, exception, query-string

I need help, I am getting the aforementioned exception. Where am I going wrong? In the mapping from class to table, I have used the following:

```
private String userId;
private String password;
```

Below is the class where I write my query.

```
public class LoginManager extends HibernateUtil {
    private String loginId;

    public String checkCredentials(String userId, String password) {

        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        try {
          loginId = (String) session.createQuery("select user_id from com.project.model.Login where user_id=:userId and password=:password") 
                                   .setParameter("userId",userId)
                                   .setParameter("password", password)
                                   .list().toString();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return loginId;
    }
}
```

Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Login")
public class Login implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;
    private String userId;
    private String password;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUser_id(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Column(name = "password")
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Hibernate cannot find your setter for the field userId. You have defined it like this:

```
public void setUser_id(String userId) { 
    this.userId = userId;
}
```

It should be:

```
public void setUserId(String userId) { 
    this.userId = userId;
}
```

Comment: I fixed that earlier. Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: @namita It may be worth posting the fix which solved your problem so others can find it.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate map your database by your variable name. So you have;

```
userId;
```

but in your query you have

```
user_id
```

You need to use `userId` not `user_id`.

And exception clearly says you provided the wrong parameter.

Answer (score -2):

Check if it is typo error

```
loginId = (String) session.createQuery("select user_id from com.project.model.Login where user_id=:userId and password=:password") .**setParameter("userId",userId)**.setParameter("password", password).list().toString();


loginId = (String) session.createQuery("select user_id from com.project.model.Login where user_id=:userId and password=:password") .**setParameter("user_id",userId)**.setParameter("password", password).list().toString();
```

Comment: Nope, that's not it. I tried it, gives a similar excpetion. "org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [user_id]"

Comment: can you send me the com.project.model.Login file with mappings.

Comment: This is it.@Entity
@Table(name = "Login")
public class Login implements Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;
 private String userId;
 private String password;
 
 @Id
 @Column(name="user_id")
 public String getUserId() {
  return userId;
 }
 public void setUser_id(String userId) {
  this.userId = userId;
 }
 
 @Column(name="password")
 public String getPassword() {
  return password;
 }
 public void setPassword(String password) {
  this.password = password;
 }}